# Vlookup within results of a multiple-match lookup

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way to return values from a table like the bottom table:

[image]

The tables are provided externally and my understanding is that I can't run filters or sorts as the table is full of extra irrelevant data that would not sort properly across all columns.

I'm approaching this twofold:

- firstly, I wanted to return the row information for any entry in the table that has a CPT matching the lookup value.
- Second, (where I'm stuck)--when the lookup returns a DESC that corresponds to a matched CPT, the goal would be to also pull in any Code A/Code B entries that correspond to that DESC value.

I found an existing formula that worked for the first part, shown below. (apologies for formatting--SO keeps flagging my draft as having unformatted code).

```
IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$3000,SMALL(IF(I$2=$A$3:$A$3000,ROW($A$3:$A$3000)- MIN(ROW($A$3:$A$3000))+1,""), ROW()-1)),"")
```

Currently, the aforementioned formula does return the DESC entries for any matching CPTs and I use vlookup to pull the rest of the relevant columns for a corresponding row.

I'm coming up short in cases where there are multiple Code A/Code B entries for a given DESC, as the lookup only returns information for the row containing the matching CPT and not any relevant codes contained in subsequent rows.

I was thinking I'd have to use something similar to the existing lookup formula to identify a matched row and then display any subsequent rows containing Code entries until the next row with a non-blank CPT entry.

Unfortunately, I don't know if that's actually the best way to approach this.  Any resources/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is still a bit unclear how you are structuring the tables and inputs, but have you considered FILTER? You might could do: `=FILTER(IF($B$3:$F$3000="","",$B$3:$F$3000),$A$3:$A$3000=I$2)`. The IF statement in the middle is intended to convert blanks to "". Otherwise FILTER will convert them to 0 which is not helpful.

Comment: If you have specific questions let me know and I'll do my best to clarify for you. As for FILTER, I don't have the 365 version of excel, so I only have FILTERXML available.